# How to select agents using (randomWhere) from Main

Tags: anylogic

What I want is to randomly select agents based on their parameters from Main. So, rather than selecting an agent by its index - `agent.get(i)` - I want to randomly select an agent by its properties.

I would love it if something like this is possible:

```
agent.get(randomWhere(agent, a -> a.age > 50 && a.health == "good" && ...));
```

I am aware that the `randomWhere` function will return the agent but, not its index. so is there a function that would do this directly?

The workaround I thought of is:

1- list all the agents using the filter function:

`List agentslist = filter( agent, p -> p.p_gender == false && ...);`

which would return something like :

```
[root.agent[1]( p_gender = false,...),root.agent[5]( p_gender = false,...),root.agent[17]( p_gender = false,...)]
```

2- I loop though the agentslist using `Regex` to get the index of each agent from what is between the `[ ]` in a new list. Based on this example this new list will have these values `[1,5,17]` .

3- Finally, I choose randomly from the new list and input its value in the `agent.get(i)` directly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the index just use the `getIndex()` function.

```
int index=randomWhere(yourAgents,a->a.age>50 && a.health.equals("good")).getIndex();
agent.get(index);
```

Remember to use equals() when you compare strings... "==" is only used effectively for primitives.

Comment: Mr. Felipe,

I think the returned output is not in a list. What can be done to get the result in a list?

Comment: List <AgentType> theList=randomWhere(yourAgents,a->a.age>50 && a.health.equals("good"));